# Inter-process communication via anonymous mmap, but without polling

Tags: python, events, ipc, mmap

I am using Python `mmap`s to exchange variables (small integers, mainly) between different instances (processes) of the same app (using `PySide6` on Windows, if that matters):

```py
import mmap
my_mmap = mmap.mmap(-1, MMAP_SIZE, "my_shared_variable")
```

I can do `my_mmap.write(my_int)` and `my_int = my_mmap.read()`, and that is all working great.

But how to know when to read?

I am currently using polling, that is, reading every millisecond or so, but I would find it much more elegant to be notified when the contents of `my_mmap` changes.

For files on the disk, I can use `QFileSystemWatcher()`, but writing/reading shared variables to/from disk is not very elegant, either.

Is there a way to watch for `mmap` content changes?

Comment: Why do you want to use `mmap` for this rather than one of [the synchronization primitives from `multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-primitives)?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica actually, I am not restricted to using `mmap` at all, I just did not see anything fitting for me in `multiprocessing`. Note that my various instances are started fully independently (user opens `app.exe` multiple times by double-clicking multiple input files), so I cannot simply "inherit" resources from some parent process. If you know another way, I'd be happy to hear :)

Comment: I have tried `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory` now, with essentially the same effect: I have to use polling.